# Send task notifications in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm making an Excel sheet in which the group leader writes a task then sends it to the worker.

I have this part figured out, but every task is sent to three people. The worker, the group leader and his assistant.

Is there a way to only send notifications about the task to the group leader and the assistant?

I have looked into TaskItem properties and found two potential solutions:

- TaskItem.StatusUpdateRecipients property
- TaskItem.StatusOnCompletionRecipients property

But I don't understand how they work. Can someone explain how they work or is there a better solution to this problem?

This is how I used these two properties:

```
With objTask

    .Assign
    .Subject = Worksheets("Naloge").Range("E" & Trow)
    .Body = "Some text"
    .Status = olTaskNotStarted
    .Importance = olImportanceHigh
    .StartDate = Worksheets("Naloge").Range("B" & Trow)
    .DueDate = Worksheets("Naloge").Range("C" & Trow)
    .ReminderTime = .DueDate - 1.5
    '.Owner = Worksheets("Naloge").Range("G" & Trow)
    '.Role = Worksheets("Naloge").Range("G" & Trow)
    .Recipients.Add (EmailTo)
    If Len(EmailCc) > 1 Then
        '.Recipients.Add (EmailCc)
        .StatusUpdateRecipients (EmailCc)
        .StatusOnCompletionRecipients (EmailCc)
    End If
    If Len(EmailVodja) > 1 Then
        .StatusOnCompletionRecipients.Add (EmailVodja)
        .StatusUpdateRecipients.Add (EmailVodja)
    End If
    .Send
    .Save
End With
```

The code stops at those two properties and shows

> Compile error: "Invalid use of property"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate a task within a public folder to assign it to another owner.

To add an additional recipient, you add a new `Recipient` object and then define its type. Type `olUpdate` leads to `StatusUpdateRecipients` and Type `olFinalStatus` to `StatusOnCompletionRecipients`.

```
Private Sub GeneratePublicTask()
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objPublicFolderRoot As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objPublicTaskFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objMyTaskFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem

    Dim objRecipientOwner As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objRecipientEveryStatusUpdate As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objRecipientFinalStatusOnly As Outlook.Recipient

    Dim EmailOwner As String
    Dim EmailEveryStatusUpdate As String
    Dim EmailFinalStatusOnly As String

    EmailOwner = "IsOwner@ACME.com"
    EmailEveryStatusUpdate = "GetsEveryUpdate@ACME.com"
    EmailFinalStatusOnly = "GetsFinalStatusOnly@ACME.com"

    Set objNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objPublicFolderRoot = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
    Set objPublicTaskFolder = objPublicFolderRoot.Folders("Public Tasks")
    Set objTask = objPublicTaskFolder.Items.Add(olTaskItem)

    ' For local folder tests:
    ' Set objMyTaskFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
    ' Set objTask = objMyTaskFolder.Items.Add(olTaskItem)

    With objTask
        .Subject = "Example Subject Text"
        .Body = "Example Body Text"
        .Status = olTaskNotStarted
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .StartDate = Date
        .DueDate = Date + 7
        .ReminderTime = .DueDate - 1.5
        .Role = "Example Role Text"

        Set objRecipientOwner = .Recipients.Add(EmailOwner)
        'objRecipientOwner.Type = olTo ' not necessary, first is To

        Set objRecipientEveryStatusUpdate = .Recipients.Add(EmailEveryStatusUpdate)
        objRecipientEveryStatusUpdate.Type = olUpdate

        Set objRecipientFinalStatusOnly = .Recipients.Add(EmailFinalStatusOnly)
        objRecipientFinalStatusOnly.Type = olFinalStatus

        .Recipients.ResolveAll

        .Assign
        '.Save

        Debug.Print .Owner      ' still yourself?
        Debug.Print .Ownership  ' 0 = olNewTask, 2 = olOwnTask, 1 = olDelegatedTask
        Debug.Print .StatusUpdateRecipients         ' Type olUpdate
        Debug.Print .StatusOnCompletionRecipients   ' Type olFinalStatus

        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it.